# android studio gives OutOfMemoryError in Viewflipper

Tags: android, arrays, out-of-memory, android-image, android-viewflipper

I am using a ViewFlipper to display images dynamically using array. The images are about 100. When I run that activity, the app stops with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:` error. The combined image size is about 7 MB. What should be done in order to display all images? Following is java code I am using.

```
ViewFlipper viewflipper;
int result_images[]= 
{R.drawable.resultone,R.drawable.resulttwo,R.drawable.resultthree,
...,R.drawable.resultonehundredsixteen};

viewflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
for(int i=0;i<result_images.length;i++)
{
    //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
    setFlipperImage(result_images[i]);
}

viewflipper.startFlipping();

private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
    Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res+"");
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    viewflipper.addView(image);
}
```

Comment: "The combined image size is about 7 MB" -- if you are referring to the size of the images on disk, that does not really matter. What matters is the size of the images in memory, which is tied to the image resolution. What is the resolution of the images (i.e., their width and height in pixels)?

Comment: @CommonsWare The images have resolution of 480x640 pixels

Comment: Try adding android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest's application tag

Comment: @MohammedJunaid I already did that, but not a luck. App still stops

Comment: Then probably scaling your images down might help

Comment: @MohammedJunaid can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: You can use glide to load/show images, lib will scale image to avoid  OutOfMemoryError

Comment: as stated in the below answer use an image loading library which efficiently loads images like Glide or Picasso as they provide methods to scale down images to lower resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of those images will consume 1228800 bytes of heap space (640 x 480 x 4 bytes/pixel), which is a bit over 1MB. 100 of them will consume ~120MB of heap space. You will not have that much heap space on many Android devices, and a `ViewFlipper` requires you to pre-load *all* of those images.

You will need to change your approach, such that you can get away with having only a few of those images in memory at once. At minimum, that will require switching from `ViewFlipper` to something else that does not require everything to be pre-loaded (e.g., use `AdapterViewFlipper`).

Plus, you will need to put those images in `res/drawable-anydpi/` or `res/drawable-nodpi/`. My guess is that you have them somewhere else (e.g., `res/drawable/`), in which case their memory consumption will grow substantially on high-resolution devices.

Comment: using `AdapterViewFlipper` made that possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use viewflipper, use viewpager from android.support.v4. Take a look at the following [sample](https://github.com/vogellacompany/codeexamples-android/tree/master/de.vogella.android.viewpager) how to use viewpager with adapter. More details can be found in the following blog [post](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/viewpager-without-fragments/).

Take a look at the following [article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).
You need to scale images and dispose them appropriately. 7 megabytes is the size of compressed images. Bitmaps consume much more space.

You can also give it a try and use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [glide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library) library to handle images effectively.